# How does a character gets promoted to an int when it is passed to printf function?

Tags: c

```
char getstr()
{
    static char s[]="GATE2016";
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s",getstr());
    return 0;
}
```

Although I know I am returning an address using a character return type , and the return type must be `char* getstr ();`

But still if I do like this only then I am getting null on gcc compiler and segmentation fault on another compiler so that means the 32-bit address value in getstr function would have been converted to a char value of 8 bits so then when I am printing that value with %s , it should be an undefined behaviour than why is it giving segmentation fault that clearly means that this 8 bit value must have been expanded to a 32 bit value , so how did this implicit conversion take place ?

Comment: Please indent your code. Also please reread your text. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: It's **undefined behaviour** to pass incorrect arguments (format mismatch). Pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined behavior, you simply can't rely in the behavior being consistent.

Comment: As for the question in your title, see e.g. [this conversions reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: you don't get the address of your char[]: char (value= G) != char* (address = 0x00000000)

Comment: "*giving segmentation fault that clearly means that this 8 bit value must have been expanded to a 32 bit value*" Why?

Comment: Narrow types such as `char` always get converted to `int` when passed in a function with `...` parameter list. This conversion is done *by value*, that is the arbitrary `char` value that your compiler made from the pointer, will be interpreted as `int`. If `char` is signed, this means that your `int` may be negative. This now completely random value is interpreted by `printf` as the address of a string, so the program crashes.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to raise several warnings.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question.

I tried this code (a little bit modified) :

```
char getstr()
{
    static char s[]="GATE2016";
    printf("in getstr : %p\n", s);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("in main : %p\n",getstr());
    return 0;
}
```

And I get

```
in getstr : 0x601040
in main : 0x40
```

We can see here that only one byte is passed by getstr, as expected.

Anyway, many printf implementations use [va_args](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg), and va_args convert every `char` or `short` into an `int`. That's how you end up with a 32bit variable.

Comment: Good explanation of what is happening. Note that printing an `int` using `%p` is UB. It works anyway in most compilers where pointers and `int` are the same size.

Answer (score -2):

It isn't being promoted at all.  Assuming that you're programming for a desktop computer, `printf` uses the stack in a clever way to allow you to pass a variable number of arguments.

The first parameter to `printf` is the format string.  This contains a run-time specification of the type and number of all of the other parameters.  Since parameters are passed by pushing 'them' onto the stack, the code can work out where each parameter is in memory based on the stack address of the format string.

In your code, you use the `%s` format specifier to tell `printf` that you have placed a pointer to an array of contiguous characters, terminated by a `\0` null character in the next position on the stack.  What you have actually placed on the stack is a single byte (`char`).  So, `printf` will read a number of bytes from the stack, including the one you placed there, that are sufficient for it to interpret as a pointer.  However, that pointer will be effectively random, since it is not a real memory address.  `printf` then attempts to read characters from that memory and the segmentation fault occurs because the memory either doesn't physically exist or is not accessible to your process.

The cause of this is probably that the `getstr` function is incorrect: it is defined as returning a single `char`, but it actually returns the least significant byte of the address of the `s` array.  You probably should define the return value as a `char*`:

```
char* getstr()
{
    static char s[]="GATE2016";
    return s;
}
```

Doing this will make the parameter passed to `printf` the correct type (a pointer to a string) and it should work as expected.